# capistrano 3.8, shared_path seems partly be ignored

Tags: ruby, capistrano

I'm working on a capistrano deployment configuration and would like to set the shared folder on another place. Background is, that I want to use a wildcard deployment (review app) and the target directory will be generated on-the-fly (which means, there isn't a shared folder in it) and I would use the shared folder with the assets across ALL review apps in this environment.

Therefore I have directories on the server:

/var/www/review/application_name

/var/www/review/application_name/shared/...  (here are the assets and configurations I would like to share across ALL review apps)

/var/www/review/application_name/branch-name/ - this is the deployment path which will be created by capistrano when deploying a specific branch to the review stage.

I have used shared_path

```
set :shared_path, "/var/www/review/#{fetch(:application)}"
```

which works fine for the linked_dirs, but NOT for the linked_files. I get the error message:

```
00:01 deploy:check:linked_files
  ERROR linked file /var/www/review/www.app.tld/123/shared/myfile does not exist on review.app.tld
```

which is true - but I don't know how to tell cap to put it in place. Of course the named file is in the shared folder

/var/www/review/www.app.tld/shared/

but capistrano seems to search on the wrong place when trying to check the linked_files (again: the linked_dirs are processed correct).

Any hints? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `shared_path` is not something you can configure directly. Using `set` will not have any effect.

The shared path in Capistrano is *always* a directory named `shared` inside your `:deploy_to` location. Therefore if you want to change the shared path, you must set `:deploy_to`, like so:

```
set :deploy_to, -> { "/var/www/review/#{fetch(:application)}" }
```

This will effectively cause `shared_path` to become:

```
"/var/www/review/#{fetch(:application)}/shared"
```

Keep in mind that `:deploy_to` is used as the base directory for many things: `releases`, `repo`, `current`, etc. So if you change `:deploy_to` you will affect all of them.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. This doesn't solve my problem, but explain the behaviour of capistrano very well. 

I have now worked around by not using linked_files but link them by myself in a task after deployment.

Answer (score 0):

If your `:application` variable is defined at some later point, or changed, you'll need to set to a deferred variable:

```
set :shared_path, -> { "/var/www/review/#{fetch(:application)}" }
```

This evaluates that string on-demand instead of in advance.

Comment: this is correct, but I think it's not the point of problem. The "deploy:check:linked_files" tries to find the files on the wrong place (inside the branch, which is also a variable) and not in the directory given in :shared_path.The deploy:check:linked_dirs, which is running just before is looking at the correct place and so the dirs are linked, but the files are not.

Comment: Maybe you have several problems and this is just one of them?

Comment: This might be - I've changed my setup to deferred variables as described by you; but without effect. As my :application variable is not (re-)defined later it should have no impact if the variable is deferred or not.